# Dificuldades com o comando FOR no Python

Tags: python, for

Eu estou montando um programa que lê informações sobre ângulos e distâncias a partir de um arquivo de texto e desenha de acordo com as informações lá contidas. O programa também deve calcular os azimutes, e foi o que eu fiz, essas variáveis que começam com `azmt` representam o azimute de cada um dos lados do polígono, entretanto eu não fiz da maneira mais inteligente, pois o código só roda para este arquivo específico ("desenho.txt").

Eu gostaria que o programa funcionasse para outros arquivos ".txt" também (claro, desde que este arquivo forneça as instruções necessárias). Já me falaram que eu poderia automatizar essa parte do código utilizando um laço do tipo `for`, mas não deu certo de maneira nenhuma. Alguém pode me dar uma sugestão?

```
import turtle
f = open('desenho.txt')
turtle.speed(1)
turtle.mode("logo")
ang = []
dist = []
azmt = []
for line in f:
    a = line.split(" ")
    ang = ang + [float(a[0])]
    dist = dist + [float(a[1])]
n = len(dist)
azmt0 = ang[0]
azmt1 = azmt0 + ang[1]
azmt2 = azmt1 + ang[2]
azmt3 = azmt2 + ang[3]
azmt4 = azmt3 + ang[4]
azmt5 = azmt4 + ang[5]
azmt6 = azmt5 + ang[6]
azmt7 = azmt6 + ang[7]
azmt8 = azmt7 + ang[8]
azmt9 = azmt8 + ang[9]
azmt10 = azmt9 + ang[10]
azmt11 = azmt10 + ang[11]
azmt = [float(azmt0)]+[float(azmt1)]+[float(azmt2)]+[float(azmt3)]+[float(azmt4)]+[float(azmt5)]+[float(azmt6)]+[float(azmt7)]+[float(azmt8)]+[float(azmt9)]+[float(azmt10)]+[float(azmt11)]
print(azmt)
for i in range(n):
    turtle.rt(ang[i])
    turtle.fd(dist[i])
turtle.done()
```

Comment: Qual é o formato do arquivo `desenho.txt`? E quais seriam os formatos dos outros arquivos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando essa parte:

> ```
> azmt0 = ang[0]
> azmt1 = azmt0 + ang[1]
> azmt2 = azmt1 + ang[2]
> ...
> azmt11 = azmt10 + ang[11]
> ```

Cada `azmtXX` é na verdade o valor de `ang` acumulado, então podemos fazer o `for` em `ang` e acumular; Fica assim:

```
azmt = []
ang_acumulado = 0
for um_ang in ang:
    ang_acumulado += um_ang
    azmt.append(ang_acumulado)
```

Dessa forma vai funcionar não importa o tamanho de `ang`

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema da repetição dos azmt utilizando um laço com duas condicionais dentro, conforme posto abaixo. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda.

```
import turtle
from math import radians, sin, cos
f = open('simples.txt')
turtle.speed(1)
turtle.mode("logo")
ang = []
dist = []
azmt = []
seno = []
cosseno = []
x = []
y = []
for line in f:
    a = line.split(" ")
    ang = ang + [float(a[0])]
    dist = dist + [float(a[1])]
n = len(dist)
for i in range(n):
    if i == 0:
        azmt.append(ang[i])
    else:
        azmt.append(azmt[i-1] + ang[i])
print("Vetor contendo os azimutes:")
print(azmt)
for i in range(n):
    seno.append(round(sin(radians(azmt[i])),7))
    cosseno.append(round(cos(radians(azmt[i])),7))
for i in range(n):
    x.append(round((dist[i] * seno[i]),4))
    y.append(round((dist[i] * cosseno[i]),4))
print("Vetor contendo as coordenadas em x:")
print(x)
print("Vetor contendo as coordenadas em y:")
print(y)
xmed = (max(x) + min(x)) / 2
ymed = (max(y) + min(y)) / 2
turtle.pu()
turtle.goto(xmed,ymed)
turtle.pd()
for i in range(n):
    turtle.rt(ang[i])
    turtle.fd(dist[i])
turtle.done()
```